# Deutsch für "can't be unseen"

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

Ich bin auf die englische Redewendung "can't be unseen" gestoßen. 
Vermutlich ist sie von "can't be undone" (kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden) abgeleitet.

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob man "can't be unseen" auch irgendwie auf Deutsch übersetzen kann.
("kann nicht rückgängig gesehen werden", und "kann nicht ungesehen werden" passen ja auf keinen Fall.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Die Bilder bekommt man nicht mehr aus dem Kopf.
```

Comment: Das ist gleichermaßen einfach wie genial. Warum bin ich da nicht selbst drauf gekommen :)

Answer (score 6):

Als Redewendung schlage ich vor

> Das wirst du / werde ich nicht mehr los

Es beschreibt, dass etwas Erlebtes einem nicht mehr aus dem Kopf geht, evtl. gar verfolgt.
Dass es hierbei um etwas Gesehenes geht, muss dann dem Kontext entnommen werden.

Comment: Die Redewendung klingt gut, *take my upvote*. Es wäre trotzdem super wenn der Bezug auf das Sehen irgendwie hergestellt werden könnte.

Answer (score 3):

Der ganze Ausdruck lautet: »**What has been seen cannot be unseen**«. Ich würde diesen Satz so übersetzen:

> Was gesehen wurde, kann nicht ungesehen gemacht werden.

Dabei geht es um zwei verschiedene Aspekte des Sehens, auf die dieser Spruch angewendet werden kann:

### 1

Das eine ist der gewöhnliche und alltägliche Akt der Wahrnehmung eines optischen Reizes. Man sieht etwas und nimmt das Abbild des Gesehenen war. Wie sehr sich dieses Abbild ins Gedächtnis einbrennt, hängt davon ab, wie außergewöhnlich oder unerwartet diese Wahrnehmung ist.

Manchmal passiert es, dass man etwas sieht, das man gar nicht sehen wollte, beispielsweise wenn man Zeuge eines Unfalls wird und Verletzungen sieht. Wenn man so etwas einmal gesehen hat, ist es schwer, diese Bilder im Kopf wieder loszuwerden. In schweren Fällen kann einen so ein Anblick, bzw. die Erinnerung daran, sogar jahrelang quälen. Wenn man so etwas gesehen kann, kann man es nicht ungesehen machen. Man kann also nachträglich den Akt der Wahrnehmung der Szenerie nicht mehr rückgängig machen.

### 2

Die zweite Art, wie dieser Ausdruck zu interpretieren ist, hat nicht mit der unmittelbaren Wahrnehmung dessen zu tun, was z. B. auf einem Bild objektiv dargestellt ist, sondern damit, was man in gewisse Formen hineininterpretiert.

Ein Beispiel:
[image: Säule im Carina-Nebel]
Dieses Bild stellt eine Säule im Carina-Nebel dar, und es ist darauf nichts weiter zu sehen als eine stellare Gaswolke. Doch wenn man die Information erhält, dass darauf eine Katze zu sehen ist, die auf den Betrachter zuspringt, während sie vor dem großen Hund flüchtet, der hinter ihr her ist, dann wird man relativ bald die Katze im Vordergrund und, teilweise von der Katze verdeckt, den Hund im Hintergrund »sehen«. Und wenn man das einmal gesehen hat, sieht man das immer wieder, sobald man das Bild sieht.

Hier ist es nicht das Bild an sich, das man nicht ungesehen machen kann, denn so aufregend ist es nicht. Bilder von stellaren Nebeln sind meist sehr schön, aber wenn man mal ein paar Dutzend davon gesehen hat, verblasst die Erinnerung an einen einzelnen Nebel recht rasch.

Bei diesem Bild ist es das, was das Gehirn hineinprojiziert, was man nicht mehr vergessen, also »ungesehen« machen kann.

Comment: Der englsche Satz hat den Fokus auf der Aktivität die das direkte Wirkungsgegenteil von "erblicken" ist. Deine Übersetzung hat den Fokus auf dem Effekt, den die Aktion auf das gesehene Objekt hat. Das ist nicht, was im Englischen gesagt wird. Es geht nicht um das Objekt, es geht um die Person die es sieht. Das "gemacht" zerstört diese Idee komplett. Daher finde ich die Übersetzung nicht gelungen. Zumal "to unsee" auch als akives Verb verwendet werden kann.

Answer (score 2):

Ich schlage ["*unvergesslich*"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unvergesslich) vor. Ferner könnte man den Sachverhalt auch mit "*nicht aus den Erinnerungen zu vertilgen*" oder mit "*nicht wieder zu vergessen*" umschreiben.

Comment: Mir fehlt dabei noch der Zusammenhang mit "sehen".
unvergesslich kann auf alles mögliche (hören, fühlen, schmecken etc.) bezogen sein.

Comment: Das passt leider gar nicht zu der Art, in der die englische Wendung meist gebraucht wird.